# Android: Extending a hidden class that is obtained through reflection

Tags: android, inheritance, reflection, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can I extend a class that is only accessible through reflection?

Basically, I am trying to extend the com.samsung.bluetoothle.BluetoothLEClientProfile class that is found in the Galaxy S3 to enable communication it with my bluetooth LE device. The class is hidden and I need to extend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dummy class in the right package (`com.samsung.bluetoothle`) in your project, then extend it. At runtime the system class will be loaded, and you should get the desired behaviour.

Comment: I spent hours trying to do this and can't believe that the solution is so simple! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I tried this solution for a java.net class that's hidden on Android studio. When extending the class with my own dummy class in the package I get an error that I cannot access the super class. If I extend the java.net class but keep the package. I get an error "trouble processing 'class'" Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*).

Comment: I have the same problem with this answer as @wesshi does, except I get `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl extended by class java.net.ECNBitsDatagramSocketImpl is inaccessible` when trying to extend that class. I filed [an issue with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165812106) but I’d really need this working on devices on the market today.