# How to extend a hidden android class

Tags: android

How can i use a hidden class?

I can use a hidden class, hidden method or hidden field through reflection.
But in my case I have to extend a hidden class and override a non-private method.

I got a solution in
[Android: Extending a hidden class that is obtained through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055419/android-extending-a-hidden-class-that-is-obtained-through-reflection)
,which uses a dummy class to dynamically replace it.

I tried it, but unfortunately i got a `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`.
I created a dummy module and a dummy class `android.app.ContextImpl$ServiceFetcher`,
then created a class in the main module to extend it.

In addition, i compiled the dummy module through `provide 'xxxx'`.
When i load the class the error will be thrown.
Anyone can help me?

Here is the code:

**dummy class**

```
package android.app;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ContextImpl {

    // The system service cache for the system services that are
    // cached per-ContextImpl.  Package-scoped to avoid accessor
    // methods.
    final ArrayList<Object> mServiceCache = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private static int sNextPerContextServiceCacheIndex = 0;

    /*package*/ static class ServiceFetcher {
        int mContextCacheIndex = -1;

        /**
         * Main entrypoint; only override if you don't need caching.
         */
        public Object getService(ContextImpl ctx) {
            ArrayList<Object> cache = ctx.mServiceCache;
            Object service;
            synchronized (cache) {
                if (cache.size() == 0) {
                    // Initialize the cache vector on first access.
                    // At this point sNextPerContextServiceCacheIndex
                    // is the number of potential services that are
                    // cached per-Context.
                    for (int i = 0; i < sNextPerContextServiceCacheIndex; i++) {
                        cache.add(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    service = cache.get(mContextCacheIndex);
                    if (service != null) {
                        return service;
                    }
                }
                service = createService(ctx);
                cache.set(mContextCacheIndex, service);
                return service;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Override this to create a new per-Context instance of the
         * service.  getService() will handle locking and caching.
         */
        public Object createService(ContextImpl ctx) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
        }
    }

    public Context getOuterContext() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**custom class**

```
package android.app;

public class V14to23ServiceFetcher extends ContextImpl.ServiceFetcher {
    @Override
    public Object createService(ContextImpl ctx) {
        // do something here
        return null;
    }
}
```

**exception code**

```
Class.forName("android.app.V14to23ServiceFetcher");
```

**full stacktrace**

```
05-19 14:55:16.813 29993-29993/? W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/android-support-v13.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
05-19 14:55:16.813 29993-29993/? I/libthemeutils: Theme： libthemeutil.so load success
05-19 14:55:16.813 29968-29968/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.app.V14to23ServiceFetcher>
05-19 14:55:16.813 29968-29968/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.app.V14to23ServiceFetcher>
05-19 14:55:16.813 29968-29968/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    Process: a.b.c.com.appres, PID: 29968
                                                       java.lang.IllegalAccessError: android.app.V14to23ServiceFetcher
                                                           at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                           at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                           at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                           at com.a.b.c.d.install(ResourcesPatch.java:227)
                                                           at com.a.b.c.e.installRes(PatchManager.java:53)
                                                           at a.b.c.com.appres.App.onCreate(App.java:29)
                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4598)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5308)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:708)
```

Comment: Post some code and the full stacktrace

Comment: see this: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Comment: @pskink thanks for your advise but i can't use multiple version because i want to cover all android version

Comment: what multiple version?

Comment: @bradley 不可以用build.version code 进行区分么？

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp 假如我按照这个思路去解决api 13~22，那我就会下载相应版本的jar包，然后替换sdk下面对应api的，编译时再build version改成相应的api（引用了全量的jar包），应该可以解决。\n但是如果我要再适配13以下，就不能同时引用多个api的jar包，因为build version只能指定一个值

Comment: just treat it a "normal" `android.jar` where all the hidden API was "unhidden"